# how to compile TF operators

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have some point clouds and I try to use [PU-GAN](https://github.com/liruihui/PU-GAN) to upsampling them. In the second step I need to compile TF operators. Actually, I'm not familiar TF so I might be in the completely wrong direction.

```
For compiling TF operators, please check `tf_xxx_compile.sh` under each op subfolder in `code/tf_ops` folder.
```

inside the subfolder "approxmatch" in tf_ops I have just try to the following command:

```
sh tf_approxmatch_compile.sh
```

Yet, i get following error :

```
fatal error: tensorflow/core/framework/op.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
```

I checked the paths and then added them.

```
TF_INC=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
TF_LIB=$(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_lib())')
```

Because of the error, I looked at the tensorflow/core/framework folder. But there is no op.h inside of it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tensorflow 1.5, python 3.6, cuda 10.0

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin/nvcc tf_approxmatch_g.cu -o tf_approxmatch_g.cu.o -c -O2 -DGOOGLE_CUDA=1 -x cu -Xcompiler -fPIC
g++ -std=c++11 tf_approxmatch.cpp tf_approxmatch_g.cu.o -o tf_approxmatch_so.so -shared -fPIC -I /home/alitokur/Softwares/try/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/include -I /usr/local/cuda-10.0/include -I /home/alitokur/Softwares/try/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/include/external/nsync/public -lcudart -L /usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/ -L /home/alitokur/Softwares/try/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core -ltensorflow_framework -O2 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
```